# android как отловить нажатие на уведомление?

Tags: android

Создаю сервис на андроиде, которые крутиться в фоне и в 12 часов обновляет данные
мне нужно чтобы он получив данные вывел уведомление - это есть!
и чтобы пользователь при клике на уведомление попал в приложение. как?

не удается повесить переход в приложение при клике.

```
package com.example.plugin; // plagin для cordova

public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        mHandler.postDelayed(ToastRunnable, sec * 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    Runnable ToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
              new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle("Новый ")
                .setTicker("  обновлен")
                .setContentText(" данные")
                .setNumber(1)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

                // вот выводим уведомление, но при клике по нему, оно просто скрывается и все
            mNotificationManager.notify("App Name", 228, mBuilder.build());

            mHandler.postDelayed(ToastRunnable, sec * 1000);

        }
    };

}
```

как задать чтобы он открыл приложение при клике?

Comment: А что в официальной документации непонятно? https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Comment: не дает мне сделать как в документации. подчеркивает красным http://prntscr.com/f40zqd

Comment: Ну так он и пишет, что нет такого конструктора с Runnable. Там нужно контекст передавать первым аргументом.

Comment: спасибо! заработало) точно поставил context и все ок

Answer (score 1):

```
  Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    resultIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);

 new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
...
...
...
...
...
.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Comment: ну я примерно также делал, у меня подчеркивает красным, я так понимаю ResultActivity.class я меняю на свой? MainActivity.class
НО он мне не дает, подчеркивает красным http://prntscr.com/f411jb

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг два одинаковых интента. и вообще код у тебя не как в ответе, смотри внимательнее